# Add button to Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to add a button in the theme customizer but can't get it to work. So far I created a panel then it shows a partial button but ideally I would like to just have a normal blue WordPress style button at the bottom under the last panel "Additional CSS". Any help is appreciated.

```
function prefix_customizer_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_id', array(
        'priority' => 300,
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'theme_supports' => '',
        'title' => __( 'Next Step', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( 'This is the next step.', 'textdomain' ),
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'section_id', array(
        'priority' => 10,
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'theme_supports' => '',
        'title' => __( 'Edit Pages', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => '',
        'panel' => 'panel_id',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'url_field_id', array(
        'default' => '',
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'transport' => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'button_id', array(
        'type' => 'button',
        'priority' => 10,
        'section' => 'section_id',
        'label' => __( 'Edit Pages', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => '',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'prefix_customizer_register' );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three things you need to do in particular.

1. As there are no settings associated with the control, you need to explicitly supply an empty array for `settings`, as otherwise it will try to look for a setting ID that matches the control ID (here `button_id`); since that setting never gets created, the control then never finishes initializing. Read more about [setting-less controls](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/10/customizer-improvements-in-4-5/).
2. Since the control is going to output an `input` element with `type=button` you need to supply the button's label via the `value` attribute of that element. You can do this by passing it via the `input_attrs` attribute.
3. Similarly, if you want to supply a custom `class` of `button button-primary` then you can do so by passing it here as well.

In short, this is what you would be looking at:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'button_id', array(
    'type' => 'button',
    'settings' => array(), // 
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'input_attrs' => array(
        'value' => __( 'Edit Pages', 'textdomain' ), // 
        'class' => 'button button-primary', // 
    ),
) );
```

Result:

[image: Button control]

Naturally this button will do nothing, so then you'd need to hook it up to custom functionality with JS using something like this:

```
wp.customize.control( 'button_id', function( control ) {
    control.container.find( '.button' ).on( 'click', function() {
        console.info( 'Button was clicked.' );
    } );
} );
```

As of WordPress 4.9-beta1, you'll be able to add a control with JS in this way (needs testing!):

```
var control = new wp.customize.Control( 'button_id', {
    type: 'button',
    settings: [],
    section: 'section_id',
    inputAttrs: {
        value: 'Edit Pages',
        'class': 'button button-primary'
    }
} );
wp.customize.control.add( control );
control.container.find( '.button' ).on( 'click', function() {
    console.info( 'Button was clicked' );
} );
```

Again, the new JS API needs testing. A dev note will be coming to [make.wordpress.org/core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/).

Comment: Testing on Wordpress 4.9.8 when adding button via JS inputAttrs should be defined as input_attrs