# Location of customizer Menu panel core code

Tags: theme-customizer, core

Where can I find the core code for the Menu customizer panel?

I want to do something that looks almost exactly like that, so I want to rely on the core code for it (I want to create a panel in which by clicking a button, new sections will be added to the panel).

Answer (score 0):

The logic to dynamically add new sections is pretty straightforward with the JS API (and will be even more so in the upcoming 4.9 release).

For dynamically adding new nav menu sections, see the relevant logic in [`wp.customize.Menus.NewMenuControl.prototype.submit`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.8.2/src/wp-admin/js/customize-nav-menus.js#L2718-L2779).

Another example you can refer to is in the [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) plugin which adds sections dynamically for each post or page being edited. See [`wp.customize.Posts.addPostSection`](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/94467b92a997fca51f68cb60b5f6b8d663900e5e/js/customize-posts.js#L391-L440) and then see the source for [`wp.customize.Posts.PostSection`](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/develop/js/customize-post-section.js).

Lastly, see my previous answer for [how to create a button control](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/282537/8521).